# JavaFX Path Transition play during n seconds and pause

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I'm doing an application with JavaFX and I have a problem.

I have an animation that follows a path, but I need the animation to be paused after n seconds and continue from the previous position other n seconds.

**Code:**

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    ImageView img1;

    @FXML
    private Path road;        

    private PathTransition anim;

    public void initialize() {

        road.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        road.setStrokeWidth(4);
        road.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(10.0, 10.0);

        // Car 1
        img1.setImage(new Image("file:src/vehicle1.png"));
        img1.setX(-img1.getImage().getWidth() / 2);
        img1.setY(300 - img1.getImage().getHeight());
        img1.setRotate(0);
        img1.setFitHeight(0);
        img1.setFitWidth(0);

    }   

    public void startRace() {

        anim = new PathTransition();
        anim.setNode(img1);
        anim.setPath(road);
        anim.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        anim.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        anim.setDuration(new Duration(6000));
        //anim.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        anim.play();

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html), to control when to play and pause your animation.

```
Timeline playtime = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), event -> anim.play()),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), event -> anim.pause()),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), event -> anim.play())
);
playtime.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this a single animation you could insert the "pause" using the Interpolator by keeping the value the same for some time:

```
public class PauseInterpolator extends Interpolator {

    private final double pauseStart;
    private final double pauseEnd;
    private final double rate;
    private final double breakFraction;

    /**
     * Constructor. It's required that {@literal pauseEnd - pauseStart < 1}.
     * @param pauseStart the start of the pause in interval [0.0, 1.0].
     * @param pauseEnd the end of the pause in interval [0.0, 1.0]. Must be
     * greater then {@literal pauseStart}.
     */
    public PauseInterpolator(double pauseStart, double pauseEnd) {
        if (pauseStart > pauseEnd || pauseStart < 0 || pauseEnd > 1 || (pauseEnd == 1 && pauseStart == 0) ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.pauseStart = pauseStart;
        this.pauseEnd = pauseEnd;
        this.rate = 1 / (1 + pauseStart - pauseEnd);
        this.breakFraction = this.rate * pauseStart;
    }

    @Override
    protected double curve(double t) {
        if (t < pauseStart) {
            return t * rate;
        } else if (t > pauseEnd) {
            return breakFraction + (t - pauseEnd) * rate;
        } else {
            return breakFraction;
        }
    }

}
```

```
...
// time to pause : pause duration : time from pause to end = 1 : 1 : 1
anim.setInterpolator(new PauseInterpolator(1d/3, 2d/3));
...
```

Note that this way you need to set the duration to the animated time plus the pause duration.